# Repeating a function containing a loop n times in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have to do a simple program that parses large text files and convert them into an excel file. My code is functional but I have an issue with the memory usage of my program.

Imagine a file containing some messages where 1 line equals to 1 message. My program basically cut the messages into pieces.
For example :

Let's say my message looks like this : 
**{{1: FOO} {2: BAR} {3: SOME MORE TEXT} ... {N: LAST INFO}}**

Once I've read this line, I put the following informations ("FOO", "BAR", "SOME MORE TEXT", ..., "LAST INFO") into a List and then I call my function insertLineIntoExcelSheet(List infos) to insert the data into a row in my excel file.

I've debugged my program and I've figured out that the memory issue comes from 
the following function :

```
public void insertLineIntoExcelSheet(List<String> line){
   Row row = sheet.createRow(nbRows++);
   int colNum = 0;
   for (String field : line) {
     Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
     cell.setCellValue((String) field);
   }
}
```

The problem is that when I have a large quantity of messages (n for instance) in my text file, the previous function is called n times and the result is that the JVM takes a lot of memory (~1GB of RAM) (When I comment this function in my code, the jvm takes only ~150MB of RAM). 
So, is there a way to optimize this function ?

P.S : I'm using Apache POI to create my excel file and add rows/cells into it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only memory being consumed in `insertLineIntoExcelSheet` would seem to be that taken up by your growing Excel worksheet.  There's no getting around that.  But what is the caller of that method doing with all those `List<String>`s  that it's passing in?  Is it keeping them around forever?

Comment: Please read https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf

Comment: @KevinAnderson The caller method just create the list and then it calls the insertLineIntoExcelSheet method with that list in parameter. The list is not stored if that's what you want to know

Comment: @AxelRichter Thank you ! Didn't know there was a streaming extension ! It works well now !

Answer (score 0):

Logically, every time you issue a sheet.createRow() (and it's cells), you're increasing the sheet's object size (more rows, bigger the sheet object, right?).

I would suggest working with chunks so you could slowly append the sheet with data but that maybe wouldn't work, you'd have to instantiate the sheet anyway and the object would still be big.

I'd try find another solution, maybe work with a less memory consumption programming language for your use case.